# How to make alarm audible over air conditioner?

Tags: sound, sleeping

I'm a heavy sleeper, but usually wake up to my iPhone alarm. I consistently sleep through it when my air conditioner is on. I can't sleep without the AC.

We're in a heatwave and I'm not going to be able to buy a different, louder alarm clock in the next few days. I've tried max volume and sleeping with my phone near my face.

How can I use my air conditioner and be jolted by my alarm in the morning?

Comment: This appears to be similar to: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/386/how-can-i-amplify-the-speakers-of-my-iphone

Answer (score 2):

Put your iPhone™ in a cup beside you. The cup will act as a directional amplifier to make the sound ***seem louder and directional***. Point the cup toward where your head is for maximum effect. Maybe that will do the trick. You may have to experiment a bit to find the optimal position for the cup/glass and your iPhone™.

Comment: You can also make a squarish tube using cardboard, cut out a hole to slot your iphone in, and cut holes in to cups the size of the square of the tube and slot it together similar to a speaker system